Infinite Scrolling Throttling Issue
I'm implementing an infinite scrolling script. This is my code:
HTML
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="loading"></div>

JS
var page = 0,
    proceed = true,
    message;
    
const load = () => {
    if (page < 10 && proceed) {
        proceed = false;
        fetch("", {
                body: "page=" + page,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                method: "POST"
            })
            .then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res))
            .then(res => {
                res.forEach(el => content.innerHTML += ...);
                page++;
                proceed = true;
            });
    }
};

window.onscroll = () => {
    var {
        scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight
    } = document.documentElement;
    if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5) load();
};

load();


Even if this code works, I think it can be improved, using a throttling technique (at least). So I changed this:
const delay = time => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time));

window.onscroll = () => {
    var {
        scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight
    } = document.documentElement;

    if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5) {
        loading.innerHTML = "Loading...";
        await delay(1000);
        load();
        loading.innerHTML = "";
};

The issue is that the "load" function is successfully called after 1 second delay, but the word "Loading..." does not appear at all.
I don't get any errors in the console.
What's wrong?

You didn't throttle precisely or at all. All you did was add delay.
Let's copy a throttling function from here
and use it to throttle the scroll function.


function throttle(mainFunction, delay) {
  let timerFlag = null;
  return (...args) => {
    if (timerFlag === null) {
      mainFunction(...args);
      timerFlag = setTimeout(() => {
        timerFlag = null;
      }, delay);
    }
  };
}

function onScroll() {
  var {
    scrollTop,
    scrollHeight,
    clientHeight
  } = document.documentElement;
  if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5) {
    loading.innerHTML = "Loading...";
    load();
  }
}

function load() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    content.innerHTML += "<p style='height: 100px; border: 1px solid red'>content</p>"
    loading.innerHTML = "";

  }, Math.random() * 1000)

}

window.onscroll = throttle(onScroll, 250)
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
please scroll to load content, responsibly

<div id="content"></div>
<div id="loading"></div>



